# How to store samba (cifs) password securely?

Tags: cifs, keyrings, smb

When a password to Windows server is needed to mount via fstab (at startup time), is there any way to keep it encrypted ? Anything better than just storing the creds in a file readable only to root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like (if your local password is the same as your windows password) password protected mounting can be realized via [pam_mount](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently#Mount_password_protected_shares_using_libpam_mount_.28Ubuntu_9.04.29).

Typical for PAM The password is obtained at logon and then used for mounting later. Not sure if this fulfills your requirements, though.

Comment: HI EIHeineken, in the wiki article you've linked the actual credentials are stored in the same way, in a file. Also, the SMb share credentials in my case are different from the Linux account. So this answer does not help me.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not the case. The user writeable file is only to configure which volumes are mounted which way. There is no password in that file. That would go against the idea of PAM and would not require the password to be the same.
If your login is different than of course (that's why I wrote "not sure if it fulfills your requirements" ..

Comment: Then, what is the credentials file mentioned several times in troubleshooting section? In the instructions from out IT it should contain the password.

Comment: The page is not solely about PAM, it describes several options to mount a share, including the credential file style. PAM nevertheless is working without a credential file :-)